# Font Issue -- Times and Computer Modern work but nothing else

Tags: fonts, packages, windows

This code seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

This is a test. 

\end{document}  %End of document.
```

But, I have had no luck with any fonts other than Times and Computer Modern.  I ran the code here (http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/garamond/) to attempt Garamond, and I received the following error:

```
pdflatex> LaTeX font warning: Font shape `T1/pgm/m/n' undefined
```

This spirals, and I finally get the LaTeX font warning that "some fonts were not available, defaults substituted."

Even if I run the deceptively simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{garamond}

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\end{document}
```

It doesn't work and I still get the same pdflatex error message.  I've also tried running this in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, and it doesn't work.

Further, this seems to happen with many, many font distributions.  I can use LuaLaTeX and an ODF or TT font; this seems to work, but I don't like the mixture of regular math and the ODF/TT.  I can't even use Euler for math!

I am running a Windows 8 machine with TeXnicCenter.  This originally started in LyX, where I tried changing the fonts through the menu, and I received very similar error messages.  When I do an internet search, there seems to be a lot of Windows 8 machines that have the same problem.  Or is it something that I am doing incorrectly?

I'm a bit of a novice, but I'm willing to try to fix the problem.  I want a different font :/

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you use `XeLaTeX`you need to add few lines to your preamble for avoid errors and can use the right fonts you want and have installed on your machine. Also I don't understand what is exactly what you want to do with fonts.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use: TeXLive or MikTeX?

Comment: I use MikTeX.  Regarding XeLaTeX -- I'd prefer to use Pdflatex, which is the default... I was hoping to use Garamond.  But none of the fonts work except for Times and Computer Modern.

Comment: Try `\usepackage{garamondx}`.

Comment: Or `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`.

Comment: @cfr: I love ebgaramond but it has no boldface up to now.

Comment: @Bernard But it is an option - not everyone needs bold in every document.

Comment: Yes but very often section titles, for instance are in boldface. And if you love maths old-style, number sets (N, Z, &c.) are in boldface. Description lists have their items in bold face (I know: this is not a universal rule; italic or small caps are just as good).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you look at CPS's comment on my answer? I think `garamondx` is not properly installed but this is MiKTeX and beyond me.

Comment: @Bernard I use very little bold in my own documents. I tend to use small-caps for section titles. For handouts, I often use a matching sans instead. (Latin Modern's sans looks semi-bold against the serif.) But, in any case, I'm not against using bold. But if you want to use EBGaramond, bold is not really part of that picture in any case. (I don't know how they typeset maths at that time but since bold wasn't around, as I understand it, I guess they did something else. So I assume maths older-old-style either didn't exist or didn't use bold.)

Comment: No never chapter titles? As for maths of that time, I've never seen any book, but as our modern notations with letters for unknowns were invented by François Viète after Garamond's death… And in Euler's books (mid 18th century) I can't remember any boldface character. I guess it's a scientific habit dating back to 19th century.

Answer (score 1):

To use a particular font with pdfLaTeX or LaTeX (as opposed to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX), you need to know either the name of a package which activates the font or the name of the font family as it is defined for LaTeX. This is not necessarily the name of the font. So although there is a package `times`, for example, there is no package, `garamond`.

The easiest way to find fonts you can use with (pdf)LaTeX is to use the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). If you want a serif font, say, click on the relevant link to get a list of possibilities. Then click on a particular font to get details of availability and usage. Some fonts may not be readily available to you but many will. For example, clicking through, I find [EBGaramond12](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/), [URW Garamond](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamond/), [Garamond Expert with mathdesign](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamondx/) and [Garamond Expert with newtxmath](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamondx-newtx/). Each page lists the lines you need to include in your preamble in order to use the font. It also tells you whether the package is part of TeX Live though I think that MiKTeX should install most things on-the-fly as necessary if you do not already have them.

Note that `times` is deprecated. You should use the instructions [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/urwnimbus/) for the URW look-alike (which is what `times` uses) or you might prefer something like [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/).

Comment: This doesn't work.  I ran the following code:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}


\begin{document}

\normalfont
This is a test.

\end{document}

I get the following error:
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 600 not found.

Comment: @CPS `garamondx` is included in MiKTeX but not TeX Live. For TL, there is a script you can use to install it. Is MiKTeX configured to install stuff on-the-fly? I think sometimes it does not install fonts entirely correctly, but is `garamondx` shown as installed in the package manager? But I can't really help you if the fonts are not installed as I have never used MiKTeX.

Comment: The most probable cause for the error is a local map file which hasn't been updated yet. Run updmap on the command line.